# Will logical facts be re-inserted when an object is updated but the updated fields from that object are not included in the rule that adds the fact?

Tags: drools

What i want to find out is will the Drools truth maintenance system re-insert a logical fact (basically update the existing one with a fresh object) when an object that is part of the rule that is inserting it is changed but none of the fields that are included in the rule have changed?

Below is an example to show what I'm talking about.
Lets say we have the two classes below:

```
public class Class1{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}
public class Class2{
    Class1 class1;
    int x;
    int y;
}
public class LogicalFact{
    Class2 class2;
}
```

And also the next two example rules which insert a logical fact which is an object from the class "LogicalFact" :

```
rule "example1"
    when
        $class2 : Class2(x > 20)
    then
        insertLogical(new LogicalFact($class2));
end

rule "example2"
    when
        $class2 : Class2(class1.x > 10, x > 20)
    then
        insertLogical(new LogicalFact($class2));
end
```

Lets say that the y field from the Class2 object ("class2") is changed and the z field from the Class1 object on which the Class2 object ("class2") is pointing at is also changed.
In the "example2" rule would the change in the field y and/or the change in the field class1.z somehow cause the rule to be re-evaluated and create and insert the logical fact again from scratch even though these values are not changed? Would it be different in the "example1" case because it only uses x, will it only be evaluated if x from the Class2 object is changed?

An edge case would be basically setting the same values again even for the fields that are part of the rule, will it even in this case insert the logical fact again?

Going further if the logical facts are being inserted again from scratch will they also re-evaluate the rules where they are used, even though there would not be any difference?

```
 /* Based on a "LogicalFact" object inserting a logical fact from the class 
 "AnotherLogicalFact". */

 rule "logical-fact-rule"
     when LogicalFact(...)
     then
         insertLogical(new AnotherLogicalFact());
 end
```

The rules in the example are simple but they might get more complex including use of accumulate functions etc. so re-evaluating the rules the rules basically for nothing would be a costly process.

Probably this is all of this is taken care of and basically what the truth maintenance system does is sticking with the already created logical fact if there is no change to the values on which the rules are based.
I just wanted to ask for an opinion to be sure.

If this turns out to be true what would be the best way to approach it?

Comment: You have to keep two things separate. A logical fact inserted on some RHS exists while some LHS side is true. How and why a LHS is re-evaluated and changes from false to true to false depends on the way the engine reacts to changes. The simple answer is that a modify/update on some fact used within that LHS is made, but there's also the "property reactive" feature - so be careful to read the small print.

Comment: Thanks @laune.
Okay "property reactive" is definitely the thing i wanted to find out. 
https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_fine_grained_property_change_listeners

Unfortunately I'm using OptaPlanner and using this feature is not currently supported. Here is a JIRA i found on their issue tracking site for implementing this feature https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-697.

So i guess i would do more important stuff now and wait for this to be implemented and then just adjust my rules.